# What's the API to undo retweets (unretweet) in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

What's the REST API call required to undo/remove/destroy/delete a retweet (of another user) from the authenticated user's timeline? There's simply no mention of this in the [API documentation on the Twitter website](https://dev.twitter.com/search/apachesolr_search/undo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Native retweet has all attributes of a simple tweet including a unique ID. So, you can use [statuses/destroy](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/destroy/%3Aid) method to remove it.

How to get that ID depends on your application. First, it's returned by [statuses/retweet](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid) method. Second, you can get user's timeline and parse out ID of this tweet.

Comment: Just curious, both these solutions don't seem complete. What if the status to undo isn't in the last 100 retweets (GET statuses/retweets/:id) or last 3200 tweets (GET statuses/user_timeline)? Those number limits seemed to be defined by the API.

Comment: @Eugene That's outside the scope of this question. There's no way to go beyond the 3,200 limit unless you try to search Twitter or get a link to the tweet from some other service. The question was only about how to undo a retweet, of which I already have the id.

Comment: To go beyond the 3200 limit, request your archive and get the IDs from it @Eugene